# How to handle pipes in this special case

Tags: c, shell, pipe, fork, posix

I create a simple pipe and the result of `ls -l /usr/bin` command is written to it using a forked (child) process. Then in the main (parent) process I just wait for the child to finish.

```
    int fd[2];
    char* arg[] = {"ls", "-l" , "/usr/bin/", NULL};

    pipe(fd);

    if (fork()==0) //child
    {
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);

        execvp(arg[0],arg);
    }
    else //parent
    {
        // close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);       
        wait(NULL);
    }
```

In the child process after I execute `dup2`, I close both end of pipes as I will not need them anymore. In the parent I close only the write end as **I need the read end**.

If this code is executed it will stall. **BUT**, if the command was `ls -l ~/Desktop/` or something similar it would terminate successfully.

Clearly `ls -l /usr/bin` command takes more time than `ls -l ~/Desktop/`, but I think it still would not matter, both of them would have to terminate.

In the parent, if I would close also the read end of the pipe,  the program would terminate (which I don't want).

What is the reason of this behavior? Is there any workaround to overcome it?

Comment: Why aren't you reading from the pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a pipe has a finite capacity (which POSIX allows to be quite small, like 4 KiB; Linux may allow up to about 64 KiB, and Mac OS X allows up to 64 KiB).  After the writing process has written that much data without a reading process doing the reading, it is blocked until the reading process reads some data, or the last reading process dies and there is no process left that can read the data.

Pipelines are for concurrent execution of programs.  You're forcing sequential execution by trying to make the first program finish before the next starts.  This is incorrect.  You need to ensure that you start all the processes in the pipeline before you do any waiting for them to finish